# How to render parameters with macros in template ext file Airflow?

Tags: sql, jinja2, airflow

I want to execute a query from a file using a parameter that has a macro on it. The parameter would be:

```
params = {'s3_path': 'dag_blabla_{{ ts_nodash }}.csv'
```

And the query that is in a file is:

```
SELECT * FROM table INTO OUTFILE S3 '{{ params.s3_path }}'
```

I have tried with the following operator:

```
s3_sta = MySqlOperator(
        task_id='s3_sta',
        mysql_conn_id='data_db',
        database='databank',
        schema='databank',
        sql='s3_sta_databank_it_products.sql',
        params={"s3_path": dag_globals['s3_sta_path'] + dag_name + '{{ ts_nodash }}.csv'}
)
```

And the output of the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM table
INTO OUTFILE S3 's3://promofarma-data/airflow/sta/import_databank_products{{ ts_nodash }}.csv'
```

However, I want it to be:

```
SELECT * FROM table
    INTO OUTFILE S3 's3://promofarma-data/airflow/sta/import_databank_products2021040815256.csv'
```

Is it possible then to have the macro `{{ ts_nodash }}` rendered within a file? Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want to render directly in the SQL code?

Comment: What do you mean?